# How to get API Connect on Cloud IP for client site whitelisting?

Tags: apiconnect

API Connect on cloud (amanged service from IBM cloud) is used which has to interact with a 3rd party external system. The 3rd party system team is asking for the IP address for whitelisting in their end. How can I get the relvant IP which needs to be shared with the external party?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.

IPs can change as topologies are updated, so any whitelisting could be invalidated without warning. This is how many cloud services work.

Instead, use a technology like [Mutual TLS (mTLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) to ensure that only the traffic you want is able to reach your endpoint. ([API Connect example](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mw-1607-hutchinson-trs/))

Since you're on IBM Cloud, you can also use the [IBM Cloud Secure Gateway](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/secure-gateway) service for this approach, especially if your backend doesn't support mTLS natively or you don't want to expose it to the internet directly.